# Java regex text replace

Tags: java, regex, replace, pattern-matching

I have  text like this

```
Some. / text to-match (1)
```

I wanna replace `./()` for `_` has next

```
Some_text_to_match_1
```

How do it the pattern?

Comment: Show your attempts.

Comment: Don't you just want to get rid of all non-word chars? Your string also contains `-` and spaces. So, there are more than `.`, `/`, `(`, `)` to deal with.

Comment: Yes i need replace all them!

Comment: See http://ideone.com/pbLPwU.

Comment: Thanks! It worked well!

Answer (score 1):

You may trim the string from non-word chars on both ends (with `.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$", "")`), and then replace 1 or more non-word character chunks with `_` inside the string (with `.replaceAll("\\W+", "_")`):

```
String s = "Some. / text to-match (1)";
s = s.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$", "").replaceAll("\\W+", "_");
System.out.println(s);
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/pbLPwU)

*Details*:

- `\W` matches a non-word character
- `+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the subpattern this quantifier modifies.

Since we need to use 2 different replacements when trimming the string and then replacing non-word chars inside it, we cannot use just 1 `replaceAll`.